# Adding a list of types to service builder

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I am trying to take a namespace find all the classes that end with service then add them as a singleton to my service.

```
foreach(Type serviceClass in GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "MyProject.Services"))
{
    services.AddSingleton<serviceClass.GetType()>;
}
```

This does not compile, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: Probably "X is a variable but is used as a type"

Comment: `services.AddSingleton<serviceClass>();` ?

Comment: If I do 
` services.AddSingleton<serviceClass>(); `

I get the error 'serviceClass' is a variable but is used like a type
I tried adding on GetType() but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach that I found is based on [this](https://github.com/JonPSmith/NetCore.AutoRegisterDi).
Would required some mother methods and classes:

You need to call this inside you `Configure`:

```
services.RegisterAssemblyPublicNonGenericClasses()
  .Where(c => c.Namespace == "")
  .AsPublicImplementedInterfaces();
```

Create this class:

```
public class AutoRegisteredResult
{
    internal AutoRegisteredResult(Type classType, Type interfaceType)
    {
        Class = classType;
        Interface = interfaceType;
    }

    public Type Class { get; }
    public Type Interface { get; }
}
```

And these methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> RegisterAssemblyPublicNonGenericClasses(this IServiceCollection services,
    params Assembly[] assemblies)
{
    if (assemblies.Length == 0)
        assemblies = new[] { Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() };

    var allPublicTypes = assemblies.SelectMany(x => x.GetExportedTypes()
        .Where(y => y.IsClass && !y.IsAbstract && !y.IsGenericType && !y.IsNested));
    return allPublicTypes;
}

public static IList<AutoRegisteredResult> AsPublicImplementedInterfaces(this IEnumerable<Type> autoRegData)
{
    var result = new List<AutoRegisteredResult>();
    foreach (var classType in autoRegData)
    {
        var interfaces = classType.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces;
        foreach (var infc in interfaces)
        {
            result.Add(new AutoRegisteredResult(classType, infc));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```